# Javascript Replace all commas not in double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I would like to replace all commas in a comma-delimited string with a pipe ('|') except for those that are found in double quotes.  I would prefer to use the JavaScript "replace" function if possible.

My regex knowledge is limited at best.  I am able to replace all commas with pipes, but that does not give me the desired result for parsing through the data.  I also found a regex on here that removed all commas except those in quotations, but does not implement a pipe or some other delimiter.

```
(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)
```

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
string1 = 1234,Cake,,"Smith,John",,"Status: Acknowledge,Accept",,Red,,
```

and I would like it to look like:

```
string1 = 1234|Cake||"Smith,John"||"Status: Ackknowledge,Accept"||Red||
```

Comment: That looks like CSV data. What happens when you want a literal `"` or newline? You're better off with a proper CSV parser.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a replace callback to replace either a quote or a comma with the quote itself or a pipe respectively:

```js
str = `1234,Cake,,"Smith,John",,"Status: Acknowledge,Accept",,Red,,`;

res = str.replace(/(".*?")|,/g, (...m) => m[1] || '|');

console.log(res)
```

Another (and IMO better in the long run) would be to use a dedicated parser to work with CSV data. CSV is actually trickier than it looks.

Answer (score 2):

We can simply capture our desired commas using alternation with a simple expression such as:

```
(".+?")|(,)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hq9I3K/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: this seems to create an extra pipe for each comma

Comment: (For each quoted string, actually. Add `,?` to the end of the left?)

Comment: When running this with global substituation, I get the following result:

1234|Cake||||||||Red||
When I would expect:

1234|Cake||"Smith,John"||"Status: Ackknowledge,Accept"||Red||